# MassTransit Testing Saga StateMachine - The state machine was not properly configured

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq, masstransit, saga

I am trying to test / execute a State Machine Saga from MassTransit but I am receiving this error

```
  Message: 
MassTransit.ConfigurationException : Failed to create the state machine connector for Invoices.Features.EntryInvoices.ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState
  ----> MassTransit.ConfigurationException : The state machine was not properly configured:
[Failure] ProcessInvoiceReceived was not specified
```

Have tried to search on the documentation but didn't find anything related. Don't know where I am missing, maybe saga configuration or something els.

here is my Saga:

```
using ...;

namespace Invoices.Features.EntryInvoices
{
    public class ProcessEntryInvoiceSaga:MassTransitStateMachine<ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState>
    {
        public State Started { get; private set; }
        public State Processing { get; private set; }
        public State Closed { get; private set; }

        public Event<ProcessInvoice> ProcessInvoiceReceived { get; private set; }
        public Event<ProductsAdded> ProductsAddedEvent { get; private set; }
        public Event<DuplicatesRegistered> DuplicatesRegisteredEvent { get; private set; }

        public ProcessEntryInvoiceSaga()
        {
            InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

            Event(() => ProcessInvoiceReceived);
            Event(() => ProductsAddedEvent);
            Event(() => DuplicatesRegisteredEvent);

            Initially(
                When(ProcessInvoiceReceived)
                    .Then(x => x.Saga.InvoiceId = x.Message.InvoiceId)
                    .Activity(x=> x.OfType<ProcessEntryInvoiceStartActivity>())
                    .TransitionTo(Started)
                );
            During(Started, 
                When(ProductsAddedEvent)
                    .TransitionTo(Processing),
                When(DuplicatesRegisteredEvent)
                    .TransitionTo(Processing));
            
            During(Processing,
                When(ProductsAddedEvent)
                    .TransitionTo(Closed),
                When(DuplicatesRegisteredEvent)
                    .TransitionTo(Closed));
            
            WhenEnter(Closed, binder => binder
                .Activity(x=>x.OfType<ProcessEntryInvoiceFinishActivity>())
            );

            SetCompleted(async instance =>
            {
                State currentState = await this.GetState(instance);
                return Closed.Equals(currentState);
            });
        }
    }

    public class ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState : SagaStateMachineInstance
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }
        public long InvoiceId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the test that I am trying to execute:

```
using ...;

namespace Invoices.Test.Features
{
    public class ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaTest
    {
        Mock<IEntryInvoiceRepository> _entryInvoiceRepository;
        ITestHarness _harness;

        [SetUp]
        public async Task Setup()
        {
            _entryInvoiceRepository = new Mock<IEntryInvoiceRepository>();
            var provider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_entryInvoiceRepository.Object)
                .AddSingleton<ISagaRepository<ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState>, InMemorySagaRepository<ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState>>()
                .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<ProcessEntryInvoiceSaga, ProcessEntryInvoiceSagaState>().InMemoryRepository();
                    cfg.AddConsumer<MockSagaStepConsumers>();
                })
                .BuildServiceProvider(true);
            _harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
            
            await _harness.Start();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task TestSetNewProductItemWithSuccess()
        {
            var openedInvoice = new EntryInvoice() {...};

            var form = new ProcessInvoice()
            {
                InvoiceId = 123
            };

            await _harness.Bus.Publish(form);

            Assert.That(await _harness.Consumed.Any<ProcessInvoice>());

            Assert.That(await _harness.Published.Any<AddProductsToInventory>());
            Assert.That(await _harness.Published.Any<RegisterDuplicatesOfInvoice>());

            Assert.That(await _harness.Consumed.Any<DuplicatesRegistered>());
            Assert.That(await _harness.Consumed.Any<ProductsAdded>());

            Assert.That(await _harness.Published.Any<EntryInvoiceClosed>());

            _entryInvoiceRepository.Verify(i => i.Update(It.IsAny<EntryInvoice>()), Times.AtLeast(2));
            _entryInvoiceRepository.Verify(i => i.SaveChanges(), Times.AtLeast(2));

            openedInvoice.Status.Should().Be(InvoiceStatus.Closed);

        }
    }

    public class MockSagaStepConsumers : IConsumer<AddProductsToInventory>, IConsumer<RegisterDuplicatesOfInvoice>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<AddProductsToInventory> context)
        {
            await context.Publish(new ProductsAdded()
            {
                CorrelationId = context.MessageId ?? Guid.Empty
            });
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RegisterDuplicatesOfInvoice> context)
        {
            await context.Publish(new DuplicatesRegistered()
            {
                CorrelationId = context.MessageId ?? Guid.Empty,
                InvoiceId = context.Message.InvoiceId
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue on

```
Event(() => ProcessInvoiceReceived);
Event(() => ProductsAddedEvent);
Event(() => DuplicatesRegisteredEvent);
```

The documentation says that the events are autoconfigured but only if they have `CorrelationId` or `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` interface.

I just added the interface `CorrelatedBy<Guid>` to my messages and set a `CorrelationID` to the first message and this allowed me to continue the process.